# File system publish method modifies all the files while publishing in vs2013

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, publish

I make some changes in aspx files and try to publish the modified files using publish method file system , after publishing bin folder shows all the files as latest modified, where as it needs to show only the changed files as modified,kindly help me on this thanks.

Comment: What do you think is wrong with such behavior? 'Publish' essentially means 'copy all'.

Comment: Yes Ondrej... but all the files are shown as recently modified.... which doesnt allow me to get the files which were changed.
 In detail...
im trying to publish my changes ... the only change is in aspx level. but when i publish all the aspx files are compiled .... I want only the changed file to be published... or shown as latest modified